# Add lines to autoplot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series

I made a plot that predicts a time series. It was achieved wih this code:

```
forecast1 <- HoltWinters(ts, beta = FALSE, gamma = TRUE) 
forecast2 <- forecast(forecast1, h = 60)    
autoplot(forecast2)
```

Where 'ts' is a time series object.
So I would like to add another time series to compare predicted values with actual values, starting from my last actual observation. I achieved it with a classical plot, adding a line with actual time series. This are the plots I have:

[image] 
[image]

How can I add this new line to my first plot?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the simplest way to do it:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forecast)

smpl1 <- window(AirPassengers, end = c(1952, 12))
smpl2 <- window(AirPassengers, start = c(1953, 1), end = c(1953,12))

hw       <- HoltWinters(smpl1, beta = FALSE, gamma = TRUE) 
forecast <- forecast(hw, h = 12)  

autoplot(forecast) +
  autolayer(smpl2, series="Data") +
  autolayer(forecast$mean, series="Forecasts")
```

[image]

The `autolayer` command from the forecast package allows you to add layers involving time series and forecasts to existing plots.